# How do I remove the background under a custom input view for a UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uikeyboard

I have set up a `UITextField` in order to display a picker view as an input view for this keyboard. I want the picker view to have rounded corners however the area under the corners still displays a background color. `pickerView.layer.masksToBound` is set to true.

My Code:

```
dummyTextField.delegate = self

pickerView.delegate = self
pickerView.dataSource = self

pickerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: 150)
pickerView.backgroundColor = offWhite
pickerView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
pickerView.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(borderWidth)
pickerView.layer.borderColor = blue.cgColor
pickerView.layer.masksToBounds = true
pickerView.clipsToBounds = true

dummyTextField.inputView = pickerView
dummyTextField.inputView?.clipsToBounds = true

let pickerToolBar = UIToolbar()
let pickerDoneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(pickerDone))
pickerDoneButton.tintColor = blue

//I also added the toolbar here

self.window.addSubview(dummyTextField)
```

[image: My Simulator]

Answer (score 0):

Use to [`clipToBounds()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622415-clipstobounds) clip view outside corners.. if your pickerView is in input view call this method on input view

```
pickerView.clipToBounds = true
textField.inputView?.clipsToBounds = true
```

> Setting this value to true causes subviews to be clipped to the bounds
>   of the receiver. If set to false, subviews whose frames extend beyond
>   the visible bounds of the receiver are not clipped. The default value
>   is false.

Comment: where you configure picker view in code or storyboard ?

Comment: It is all programmatic.

Comment: can you update your question with that code ? so that i can figure out whats wrong in that

Comment: can you share the project via wetransfer ? it all seems good enough ..i want to see it in view hierarchy

Comment: How do I send it? I've never used wetransfer I only see a way to send by email

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214218/discussion-between-jawadali-and-user197974).